# What is the language of Allah?

Tags: allah, language

What is the language of Allah?

In what language does Allah talk to His angels and give orders?

In what language will He give orders on the Day of Judgement?

We know that Quran was sent in Arabic. In what language Torah, Zabur, Enzil and other divine books were written when they were sent first?

Comment: Why do you assume it's a language as we know it?  Maybe their communication method requires no use of sound waves?

Comment: @oshirowanen, you are right, even Quran is not indeed in Arabic, it only appears as Arabic after revelation, as revelation (نزول) here means bringing down a concept not from sky but from a deep position to somewhere that is understandable to all. By the way, the detailed way how Inspiration took place from Allah to Gabriel then to the prophets exists in Ahadeeth from Ahlul Bayt, I have read them some weeks ago although I'm not sure where I saw that. Allah Himself of course has no language, no sound, no mouth, but the question is a good one, so +1 for me :)

Comment: I'd be quite surprised if you can get a reliable answer for this. Maybe look into the details of Allah speaking directly to the Prophet Musa AS or Adam AS, perhaps in the older scriptures.

Comment: It could even be Hebrew/Assyrian/Canaanite, as Musa/Abraham spoke directly to Allah without intervention from angels. Allah is all-knowing and can switch languages at will.

Comment: Isn't there a verse in the Quran, or perhaps some hadith saying that Allah will communicate with the Prophet Muhammad in an unknown language (on The Day of Judgement)?

Comment: Thats is one of the questions of not should be asked for public to answer...this needs "aalim".. Anyway ww know allah qadeer to do anything...and he is the one who CREATED the languages...and the tongues of all ppl...so we cant say allah has a language except if hadeeth says so

Comment: What is "aalim"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quran is in arabic because it was the language of the people where it was revealed. It does not make sense to reveal it in any other language. Same had been the case with other revelations. It does not mean that Allah prefers one language over another, as all languages are made by man and suffer its own limitations.

How Allah communicates with angels is "ghaib".